# Mathematical expression in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, math, formula

Please see the formulæ below.

It's the solution to a circle chord problem where A is the arc length and C is the chord length.
I want to find the Radius r.

The formula below uses factorials and powers etc which I don't know how to express in Objective C.

Can somebody help by converting the formula into Objective C language?

```
a = A² – C²
b = -2A^4/4!
c = 2A^6/6!
d = -2A^8/8!

//Let:
f = c/a-b²/3a²

g = d/a+2b³/27a³-bc/3a²

x = cuberoot(-g/2 + sqrt(g²/4+f³/27)) – cuberoot(g/2 + sqrt(g²/4+f³/27)) - b/3a

r = sqrt(x)
```

Comment: why is my question being down voted when it is a valid question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
double factorial(int x)
{
    double result = 1;
    for (x = x; x > 0; x--)
    {
        result *= x;
    }
    return result;
}
```

...

```
int A = 20;
int C = 25;

double a = A*A - C*C;
double b = -2.0*pow(A, 4.0)/factorial(4);
double c = 2.0*pow(A, 6.0)/factorial(6);
double d = -2.0*pow(A, 8.0)/factorial(8);

//Let:
double f = c/a-(b*b)/(3.0*(a*a));

double g = d/a + 2.0*pow(b, 3.0)/(27.0*pow(a, 3.0))-(b*c)/(3.0*a*a);

double x = pow(-g/2.0 + sqrt(g*g/4.0+pow(f, 3.0)/27.0), 1.0/3.0) - pow(g/2.0 + sqrt(g*g/4.0+pow(f, 3.0)/27.0), 1.0/3.0) - b/(3.0*a);

double r = sqrt(x);
```

Comment: It seems silly to write a recursive function to generate 3 constants. 4!=24. 6!=720. 8!=40320

Comment: It doesn't hurt. Anyway, it's iterative, not recursive ;-)

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for your comprehensive solution. i've tried the code in my application, but i've a problem. if i use 20 for A and 25 for C i get the following a = 225 b = nan c = 1.033137 d = nan f = nan g = nan x = nan and r = nan.... what do you think is going wrong . thanks

Comment: I've updated my answer - try it now, I think I may have gotten the brackets in the wrong place for the b, c, and d values.

Comment: Hi Nick, actually  your update doesn't help the situation it makes it worse. i think the problem is coming from the factorial calculations initially, as when i use the factorial method, i get different results than if i simply use constants as suggested by woodchips. any ideas?

Comment: I've tweaked the first 4 calculations again, based on some Googling of operator precedence. But the factorial function is/was definitely giving the right values for me, for example factorial(3) gives 6.0 and factorial(4) gives 24.0, which are both correct so perhaps you copied it wrong? It would help if you could tell me what values you are expecting for a, b, c and d. Right now I get -225, -13333.333, 177777.777 and -1269841.269841, but I've no idea if those are right or not.

Comment: hi nick, sorry ive not responded sooner, ive been away with work. now im back in the saddle i changed my formula completely to use newtons method to solve my problem. i'm now getting the results i need, without using factoring. as it happens the factoring results are all correct as you stated, but my formula itself had some issue returning a nan when it should'nt have.

Answer (score 2):

The header is `<math.h>`.  You square by multiplying a factor by itself; you cube by multiplying a factor by itself twice.  The factorials are constants; you precalculate them, or let the computer do so:

```
enum { factorial_3 = 1 * 2 * 3 };  // Not needed, but an example
enum { factorial_3 = 3 * factorial_2 };  // Alternative technique
```

The function `sqrt()` gives you the square root.  If it is available, then `cbrt()` from C99 gives you a cube root.  When it isn't available, you can use `pow()` instead.  If the notation `A^4`, `A^6` and `A^8` is equivalent to `A`<sup>`4`</sup>, `A`<sup>`6`</sup>, `A`<sup>`8`</sup>, then those are easily handled as multiplications.

You can assemble the bits and pieces using this information.

Answer (score 1):

For exponents, you can use math.h(which you'll need to import)'s `pow(float base, float exponent)` function.  Then for factorials, you'll have to create one yourself. The following function should work (I didn't try it out yet).

```
long factorial(int number)
{
    long numb = 1;
    for (int i=1;i<=number;i++)
    {
        numb*=i;
    }
    return numb;
}
```

However, be aware that it's very easy to get too huge numbers with factorials, so use long long (or even malloc if necessary) if you need to get the factorial of a large number.

Comment: or in short `long factorial(int n) { if (n <= 1) { return 1; } return n * factorial(n-1); }`